# Implications for QM of "Photoionization in the time and frequency domain"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

"[Photoionization in the time and frequency domain](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01780)", a recent paper published in AAAS Science, purportedly falsifies the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle.  Quoting [the ScienceDaily article on this paper](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/11/171113104709.htm):

> The new measuring technique circumvents the limitation formulated by
>   the father of quantum physics, Werner Heisenberg, in 1927. According
>   to "Heisenberg's uncertainty principle," it is not possible to
>   determine the position and the speed of an electron at the same
>   instant. However, now, the Swedish researchers have shown that it can,
>   in fact, be done: through superposition (i.e. interference) of two
>   short pulses of light with different wavelengths.

What are the implications for quantum mechanics if the results of this experiment are replicated?

What, if any, relationship does this experiment have to [Popper's Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popper%27s_experiment) as proposed in "[Realism in Quantum Mechanics and a New Version of the EPR Experiment](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-009-5245-4_1)"?

Comment: As usual, the actual paper does not claim to falsify the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle. This experiment is akin to looking at both the time-trace of a radio signal and its Fourier transform at the same time. If you choose bandwidths carefully you can get both good time and frequency resolution.